# How to fix the foot still in walking animation?

Tags: animation

When you tread the ground with your foot it will be still on the ground like below, in turn making you go forward by frictional force.

The problem is that when I animate it, I have to move the thigh bone in turn making the food stray from the original position. So it's extremely fiddly and painful to just make a single foot stay where it was. As I made keyframes every frame it looks better but something's off since the foot now judders and it took me an hour and a half.

How am I then suppose to make it natural?

[image]

Comment: you should use inverse kinematic for rigging legs

Comment: @covector Thanks I'll search for a tutorial for it. One thing though, whenever the model moves forward I have to move the entire bone to the front and adjust the rest of the bones to the back. If I do the kinematic thingy can I skip that process?

Comment: Yes, inverse kinematic is basically making the feet bone always stay where it is and when you move the body bone forward, the feet bone will not move and also the bones in the middle will connect correctly automatically.